# Using Xiaomi Mi Band for a Indoor Navigation System

Tags: bluetooth, beacons, wearables

I have to use a Xiaomi Mi band 6 for receiving the BLE signal strength from some beacons deployed in a room in order to track user's position. My initial plan was to develop a wearable App that collect beacon RSSIs (signal strengths), and forwarding them to a gateway. Unfortunately, Xiaomi Mi band 6 have not the Wear OS onboard, so I am trying to understand how it can be programmed in order to finally implement this scenario.

Comment: what is the actual difficulty that you have?

Comment: You’ll probably save a lot of time and energy by switching to another watch which is designed to support custom apps or firmware, as this one seems to have a closed ecosystem.

Comment: unfortunately, I am forced to use a Xiaomi Mi band 6. My difficulty relies in the fact that I don't know how to build and install an application for MIUI Band OS 10. I am also exploring the possibility to read RSSI data from an associated Android phone without the need to install code into the wearable.